# Can't Connect to Postgresql DB Through Node on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, postgresql, pg

When I try to connect to my database (on a Linux machine) through the command line I'm able to do so just fine:

```
$ psql -U me -W
Password for user me: 
psql (9.5.7)
Type "help" for help.

me=#
```

I can also access it without a password:

```
    $ psql -U me # this works
```

However, when I try to connect through the Node library `knex` (which just uses `pg` under the hood) I get the following error:

```
error: password authentication failed for user "me"
```

I think it has something to do with the combination of Linux users/Postgres users that are setup in Linux, but nothing I've tried has fixed it.  I tried altering my connection URL string, but even a correct one (I think) doesn't work:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost:5432/mydb
DATABASE_URL=postgres://me:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydb
# (neither works)
```

I also tried adding:

```
host mydb me 127.0.0.1/32 trust
```

to my `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf`, but that didn't help either.

I'm pretty sure I just have to somehow tell Node "use this user/password" in the correct way ... but I can't figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I tried setting my `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` to just:

```
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32         trust
host    all         al          ::1/128              trust
```

or in other words "let everyone in without a password".  When I `psql -W` it now accepts any password I enter ... but even so I still get the:

```
error: password authentication failed for user "me"
```

error when Node/`knex`/`pg` try to connect.

Comment: Which PostgreSQL client library do you use?

Comment: `knex` (which uses `pg`)

Comment: Is it related [knex GitHub issue](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1371) ?

Comment: I do not believe so; I'm running version 0.13.0 of Knex, which is well past the fix for that issue.  I did try clearing my `node_modules` folder and reinstalling, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up getting things working by:

A) Adding a rule to `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` to always trust connections over `localhost`:

```
host    all         all         localhost            trust
```

B) Using a connection URL of:

```
postgres://me:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydb
```

Comment: For me (on Fedora 27) `pg_hba.conf` is at `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that UNIX domain sockets are not receiving preferential treatment with node.js.

Based on a [test for `pg-connection-string`](https://github.com/iceddev/pg-connection-string/blob/master/test/parse.js#L42), I suspect that

```
socket:///var/run/postgresql/?db=mydb
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried using that as my connection string (with `mydb` replaced of course), but unfortunately I still get the same error.  I tried without `?db=mydb` too; no luck.

Comment: Have you tried the object-based configuration (without a URL)?

Comment: My team has it configured to use object-based config, but that config uses a URL: `{
  env: env.NODE_ENV,
  isDev: env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  serverPort: env.PORT || 4000,
  database: {
    connection: env.DATABASE_URL,
  },
}`.  I'd like to avoid changing that so that I don't break all my (Mac-using) coworkers settings ... and surely there's some way to make `knex`/`pg` work with a connection URL on Linux?

Comment: Oh, this is an intriguing problem. I think the URL parser in `pg-connection-string` is simply broken and does not implement the specification in the PostgreSQL documentation, so I'm not sure if there is a way to avoid the connection object.

Comment: But connection strings work fine for my mac-using co-workers, and the `pg` library had 40k people download it ... just yesterday, so I find it hard to believe the library could have such a major bug.  Could you elaborate on what's broken about `pg-connection-string`?